# Add Custom Domain for Static Website on Azure

Tags: azure

I'm trying to use Azure Static Website(preview) to deploy my hexo website. I followed instructions on microsoft doc and when I try to add my cname configured custom domain name for this static website. It took me a very long time to see this info in activity logs(validation passed already):

- Create Static Site Custom Domain
  Accepted
  14 hours ago
- Create Static Site Custom Domain
  Started
  14 hours ago
  But I never see a successfully complete creation info in logs. and when I try to add that domain one more time, it tells me:

`Request Envelope is invalid. Please ensure the custom domain is not linked to another site.`

Anyone can help me with this please? Really don't know what happended..

Comment: what is the domain you added?

Comment: " Really don't know what happended." - the error message is quite straightforward. It means you, or someone else, is already using the same custom domain-name on another Azure Static Website or Azure App Service.

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that I can see Create Static Site Custom Domain Started but never see it succeed, so maybe my custom domain just hang in there? because before I click the `Add` button, validation is successful.

Comment: How did you solved? Awswer your question to help others.